# nifi and http on Linux

Tags: http, apache-nifi

Does nifi use the http server on Linux or does it use it's own?  I inherited a nifi server that has some nessus issues related to http.  Http service is not running, only nifi.  Tring to figure out how to resolve the issues.

Comment: nifi has own http server

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> NiFi executes within a JVM on a host operating system. The primary
>   components of NiFi on the JVM are as follows:
>
> Web Server
>
> ```
> The purpose of the web server is to host NiFi’s HTTP-based command and control API.
> ```
>
> ...

More info : https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/overview.html